# How to use sudo classes with SASS and Angular

Tags: angular, sass

So I have this .scss file that correctly gets the base style but fails to get the styling for the sudo class :hover.

Here is homepage.scss

```
.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color : rgb(39,82,180);
  cursor: pointer;
  
  & :hover {
      color :"#002447";
  }
}
```

And here is the relevant code in homepage.component.html

```
<li><button class="link" role="link" (click)="dostuff()">Remote Support</button></li>
```

The color shows up correctly and so does the cursor and the text is underlined as expected.
However, the color does not changed during hover.

How can I make the text color change when hovered? Would strongly prefer a sass solution to a js/angular one.

I have also tried the more traditional CSS approach which also did not work.

```
.link  {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color : rgb(39,82,180);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link :hover {
  color :"#002447";
}
```

We can see the hover sudo class is not present.
[image: no hover]

But we can see the other styles show up correctly in chrome developer console
[image: other styles]

I have also tried removing the space between :hover and &, I have also tried removing the same space in the CSS version.

In my package-lock.json I have these specific versions of SASS.

"sass": "1.23.3",

"sass-loader": "8.0.0",

I am also using foundaton.css and font-awesome in case there are any known conflicts.

Comment: Did you try `&:hover`, without any space?

Comment: .link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color : rgb(39,82,180);
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &:hover {
      color :"#002447";
  }
}

Comment: @Roy, yes I did try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No space is needed between the `&` and `:hover`. Leaving that there compiles to css that looks like this:

```css
.link :hover {
//...
}
```

This is obviously incorrect. Instead we would want the compiled css to look like this:

```css
.link:hover {
  //...
}
```

Instead do:

```
.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color : rgb(39,82,180);
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &:hover {
      color : #002447;
  }
}
```

Edit: As a general tip and something that helps me out, if I am curious about how something in SCSS compiles to CSS, I go [try out the SCSS in Codepen](https://codepen.io/MikeVMWork/pen/LYRpmYB) and check what it compiles to.

Edit 2: Removed the quotes around the hex code. See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/MikeVMWork/pen/mdreLrZ)

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not resolve the issue. The style does not appear visually or in the chrome developer console.  I can search the styles section for "hov" or ".link" and the hover portion does not appear.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett are you sure you are doing it correctly? Because in your question, you show that you do not declare the pseudo selector properly several times. Having a space between the `.link` and `:hover` is incorrect. Also, your hex does not need to be in quotes. Remove them from around `#002447`

Comment: I thought I copied and pasted it but apparently I had not. I just removed the space. Your version seems to work. I will mark it as the accepted answer. It looks like I accidentally put quotes around the color which is why removing the space did not appear to work.